# How do I send a file to the Django server via ajax?

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I can't figure out for more than a week, I need to send an image to the Django server, but I get the error: **415 (Unsupported Media Type)**

If I change ContentType to multipart/form-data, I get:
**400 (Bad Request)**

is sent via postman normally, what could be the error?: (

Script

```
    updateUser() {
      $.ajax({
        url:
          "http://localhost:8002/api/update_profile/" +
          this.username +
          "/",
        data: {
          first_name: this.first_name,
          username: this.login,
          last_name: this.last_name,
          email: this.email,
          photo: this.image
        },
        DataServiceVersion: 2.0,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        // contentType:"multipart/form-data",
        type: "PUT",
        success: function(data) {
          location.reload()
        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(this.data)
          let err = response.responseJSON;
          for (let key in err) {
            alert(key, err[key].toString());
          }
        }
      });
  },
```

UPD. it doesn't work either form data

```
    updateUser() {
      const data = {
          username: this.login,
          first_name: this.first_name,
          last_name: this.last_name,
          email: this.email,
          photo: this.image
      }
      let formData = new FormData()
      Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
        formData.append(key, data[key])
      })
      $.ajax({
        url:
          "http://localhost:8002/api/update_profile/" +
          this.username +
          "/",
        data: {
          formData
        },
        DataServiceVersion: 2.0,
        processData: false,
        //contentType: false,
        contentType:"multipart/form-data",
        type: "PUT",
        success: function(data) {
          loaction.reload()
        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log(this.data)
          let err = response.responseJSON;
          for (let key in err) {
            alert(key, err[key].toString());
          }
        }
      });
  },
```

Comment: form postman how are you sending the data is it raw data or form data?

Comment: @Sumithran, I am sending the form data

Comment: Can you share your view? Sharing only javascript code is not enough to figure out whats wrong but if you're using Django Rest Framework and class based views you may missed the `parser_classes` attribute on your view.

Comment: @arif, yes, indeed, there was a problem with loading the image, on the Django side. Thank you, I was thinking in the wrong direction!

Answer (score 0):

i think you change "contentType" to "application/json" or "'application/json; charset=utf-8" if you need utf-8. dataType :'json'

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```